# Javascript/HTML random character placed at bottom of page

Tags: javascript, html

[Random Character example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYAng.jpg) Is a link to a picture of my web page. 
I can't find the location where the > symbol at the bottom of the page is generated. I've used cmd f to search the code for a random one and none seem to be misplaced. It's not very intrusive, nonetheless, I like to understand my code.

Also, I do not understand why my for loop is not activating.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>The web site of matt9878</title>
    <!-- The style.css file allows you to change the look of your web pages.
         If you include the next line in all your web pages, they will all share the same look.
         This makes it easier to make new pages for your site. -->
    <link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div class="outputText">
      
      <!-- Equations assighment -->
      <p id="equation"> Equation assighment: <br/></p>
      
      <!-- Counting Coins assighment -->
      <p id="combinations"> Coin combo assighment: <br/></p>
      
      <!-- Timely Mesasurements assighment -->
      <p id= "circumference"> Timely Mesasurements assighment: <br/></p>
         
      <!-- Blackjack assighment -->   
      <p id="blackjackTotal"> Blackjack assighment: <br/></p>
      
      <!-- Prime Time Assighment -->  
      <p id="primeTime"> Prime Time assighment: <br/></p>
      
      
    </div>  
       
    <!-- Greetings assignment -->
    <script>
      window.alert("Hola, Como esta?");
    </script>
    
    <!--Equations assighment-->
    <script>
      
      for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
      {   
        var x = Math.round(Math.random() * 1500);
        var y = Math.round(Math.random() * 1500);
        
        document.getElementById("equation").innerHTML += x + " + " + y + " = " + (x + y) + "<br/>";
      }
      
      //*seriesOfEquations();
    </script>
    
    <!-- Counting Coins assighment -->
    <script>
      var value = 175;
      
      var penny = 1;
      var nickel = 5;
      var dime = 10;
      var quarter = 25;
      
      document.getElementById("combinations").innerHTML += (value / penny) + "(" + penny + ")" + " = " + value + "<br/>";
      document.getElementById("combinations").innerHTML += (value / nickel) + "(" + nickel + ")" + " = " + value + "<br/>";
      document.getElementById("combinations").innerHTML += Math.floor(value / dime) + "(" + dime + ")" + 
        " + " + nickel + " = " + value + "<br/>";
      document.getElementById("combinations").innerHTML += (value / quarter) + "(" + quarter + ")" + " = " + value + "<br/>";
      
    </script>
    
    <!-- Timely Mesasurements assighment -->
    <script>
      var date = new Date();
      var rad = date.getHours();
      
      document.getElementById("circumference").innerHTML += (2 * Math.PI * rad).toFixed(3) + "<br/>";
    </script>
    
    <!-- Blackjack assighment -->>
    <script>
      //Card dealing
      var cardOne = (Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10 ) + 1);
      var cardTwo = (Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10 ) + 1);
      var combined = cardOne + cardTwo;
      
      var cardValues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];
      
      //Ace checking
      if (cardOne == 11 && combined > 21) {
        cardOne = 1;
        combined = cardOne + cardTwo;
      }
      else if (cardTwo == 11 && combined > 21) {
        cardTwo = 1;
        combined = cardOne + cardTwo;
      }  
    
      //Dealer hit sequence
      if (combined < 17) {
      
        document.getElementById("blackjackTotal").innerHTML += "The dealer is hitting thier current total of " + combined + "<br/>";
        
        cardOne = (Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10 ) + 1);
        
        //Ace checking
        if (cardOne == 11 && (combined + cardOne) > 21) {
          cardOne = 1;
          combined = combined + cardOne;
        }
        else {
          combined = combined + cardOne;
        }
      }
   
      //Blackjack
      if (combined == 21) {    
        document.getElementById("blackjackTotal").innerHTML += "Blackjack!!!!" + "<br/>";   
      }
      
      //Dealer bust 
      else if (combined > 21) {
        document.getElementById("blackjackTotal").innerHTML += "The dealer has gone bust with a total of " + combined + "." + "<br/>";
      }
      
      //Dealer total ancouncement
      else{
        document.getElementById("blackjackTotal").innerHTML += "The dealer's total is " + combined + "." + "<br/>";
      }
      
    </script>
    
    <!--  Prime time assighment -->
    <script> 
      var numOne = Number(prompt("Please enter the first whole number to begin the range you'd like to explore."));
      var numTwo = Number(prompt("Enter the second whole number to conclude the range you'd like to explore. Hint: Second choice > first."));
      
      window.alert(numOne + ", " + numTwo);
      
      if (numOne < numTwo && (numOne.isInteger() && numTwo.isInteger())) {
        for(; numOne <= numTwo; numOne++) {
          document.getElementById("primeTime").innerHTML += numOne + ", " + numTwo + "<br/>";
        }         
      }
      else {
        window.alert("Please reload the webpage and try again. Error code: User error.");
      } 
    </script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The error is not reproducible, please share the source code that reproduces the error shown in the attached image.

Comment: @A.J. Try canceling all alerts, you can reproduce it. It is below `Prime Time assighment: `

Comment: Search for `>>` in your code. Bingo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line 77 there was an extra `>` in a comment:

```
<!-- Blackjack assighment -->>
```

Which runs as

>

Fixed:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>The web site of matt9878</title>
    <!-- The style.css file allows you to change the look of your web pages.
         If you include the next line in all your web pages, they will all share the same look.
         This makes it easier to make new pages for your site. -->
    <link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div class="outputText">
      
      <!-- Equations assighment -->
      <p id="equation"> Equation assighment: <br/></p>
      
      <!-- Counting Coins assighment -->
      <p id="combinations"> Coin combo assighment: <br/></p>
      
      <!-- Timely Mesasurements assighment -->
      <p id= "circumference"> Timely Mesasurements assighment: <br/></p>
         
      <!-- Blackjack assighment -->   
      <p id="blackjackTotal"> Blackjack assighment: <br/></p>
      
      <!-- Prime Time Assighment -->  
      <p id="primeTime"> Prime Time assighment: <br/></p>
      
      
    </div>  
       
    <!-- Greetings assignment -->
    <script>
      window.alert("Hola, Como esta?");
    </script>
    
    <!--Equations assighment-->
    <script>
      
      for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
      {   
        var x = Math.round(Math.random() * 1500);
        var y = Math.round(Math.random() * 1500);
        
        document.getElementById("equation").innerHTML += x + " + " + y + " = " + (x + y) + "<br/>";
      }
      
      //*seriesOfEquations();
    </script>
    
    <!-- Counting Coins assighment -->
    <script>
      var value = 175;
      
      var penny = 1;
      var nickel = 5;
      var dime = 10;
      var quarter = 25;
      
      document.getElementById("combinations").innerHTML += (value / penny) + "(" + penny + ")" + " = " + value + "<br/>";
      document.getElementById("combinations").innerHTML += (value / nickel) + "(" + nickel + ")" + " = " + value + "<br/>";
      document.getElementById("combinations").innerHTML += Math.floor(value / dime) + "(" + dime + ")" + 
        " + " + nickel + " = " + value + "<br/>";
      document.getElementById("combinations").innerHTML += (value / quarter) + "(" + quarter + ")" + " = " + value + "<br/>";
      
    </script>
    
    <!-- Timely Mesasurements assighment -->
    <script>
      var date = new Date();
      var rad = date.getHours();
      
      document.getElementById("circumference").innerHTML += (2 * Math.PI * rad).toFixed(3) + "<br/>";
    </script>
    
    <!-- Blackjack assighment -->
    <script>
      //Card dealing
      var cardOne = (Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10 ) + 1);
      var cardTwo = (Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10 ) + 1);
      var combined = cardOne + cardTwo;
      
      var cardValues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];
      
      //Ace checking
      if (cardOne == 11 && combined > 21) {
        cardOne = 1;
        combined = cardOne + cardTwo;
      }
      else if (cardTwo == 11 && combined > 21) {
        cardTwo = 1;
        combined = cardOne + cardTwo;
      }  
    
      //Dealer hit sequence
      if (combined < 17) {
      
        document.getElementById("blackjackTotal").innerHTML += "The dealer is hitting thier current total of " + combined + "<br/>";
        
        cardOne = (Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10 ) + 1);
        
        //Ace checking
        if (cardOne == 11 && (combined + cardOne) > 21) {
          cardOne = 1;
          combined = combined + cardOne;
        }
        else {
          combined = combined + cardOne;
        }
      }
   
      //Blackjack
      if (combined == 21) {    
        document.getElementById("blackjackTotal").innerHTML += "Blackjack!!!!" + "<br/>";   
      }
      
      //Dealer bust 
      else if (combined > 21) {
        document.getElementById("blackjackTotal").innerHTML += "The dealer has gone bust with a total of " + combined + "." + "<br/>";
      }
      
      //Dealer total ancouncement
      else{
        document.getElementById("blackjackTotal").innerHTML += "The dealer's total is " + combined + "." + "<br/>";
      }
      
    </script>
    
    <!--  Prime time assighment -->
    <script> 
      var numOne = Number(prompt("Please enter the first whole number to begin the range you'd like to explore."));
      var numTwo = Number(prompt("Enter the second whole number to conclude the range you'd like to explore. Hint: Second choice > first."));
      
      window.alert(numOne + ", " + numTwo);
      
      if (numOne < numTwo && (numOne.isInteger() && numTwo.isInteger())) {
        for(; numOne <= numTwo; numOne++) {
          document.getElementById("primeTime").innerHTML += numOne + ", " + numTwo + "<br/>";
        }         
      }
      else {
        window.alert("Please reload the webpage and try again. Error code: User error.");
      } 
    </script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. I should've searched >>. I'll keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 0):

just above card dealing code, there is extra '>' in commented blackjack assignment. Hope it will help

Comment: Thanks. Dumb mistakes....